# React-bootstrap modal not popping up even after showModal is set to true

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, reactjs, react-bootstrap

I have used this in previous projects and it worked just fine. I thought that maybe the `state` of `showModal` wasn't getting set, but it is getting set to true when I click the pictures. I will post code below.

Please let me know if you need anymore information rather than spamming the down-vote, help create a better community :)

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { Modal } from 'react-bootstrap';

class Gallery extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
      showModal: false
    };
  }

  render() {
    console.log(this.state);
    const { gallery } = this.props;
    return (
      <section id="gallery" className="three">
        <div className="container">
          <header>
            <h2>{gallery ? gallery.title : 'Select A Gallery'}</h2>
          </header>
          <div className="card-deck">
            {gallery
              ? gallery.images.map((image, i) => (
                  <div key={i} className="card">
                    <img
                      onClick={() => {
                        this.setState({ showModal: true });
                      }}
                      className="card-img"
                      src={`${image}=s1000-c`}
                      alt="Card image cap"
                    />
                  </div>
                ))
              : null}
          </div>
          <Modal
            bsSize="sm"
            show={this.state.showModal}
            onHide={() => this.setState({ showModal: false })}
          >
            <Modal.Header closeButton>
              <Modal.Title>Purchase Item</Modal.Title>
            </Modal.Header>
            <Modal.Body>Hello</Modal.Body>
          </Modal>
        </div>
      </section>
    );
  }
}

export default Gallery;
```

EDIT: modal is showing up upon `inspect` here are two pictures to show:
[image]

---

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code seems ok (see below how it runs just fine).
The only thing i can think of is that you forgot to include the [bootstrap css](https://www.bootstrapcdn.com/) file in your page.
You see, `react-bootstrap` is not injecting the actual css, its just generating components with css class names.

```js
const {Modal} = ReactBootstrap;
const gry = {
  images: [
    'http://via.placeholder.com/350x150',
    'http://via.placeholder.com/350x150',
    'http://via.placeholder.com/350x150',
  ]
};


class Gallery extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
      showModal: false
    };
  }

  btnClick = () => {
    this.setState({ name: 'Sarah' });
  }

  render() {
    console.log(this.state);
    const { gallery } = this.props;
    return (
      <section id="gallery" className="three">
        <div className="container">
          <header>
            <h2>{gallery ? gallery.title : 'Select A Gallery'}</h2>
          </header>
          <div className="card-deck">
            {gallery
              ? gallery.images.map((image, i) => (
                <div key={i} className="card">
                  <img
                    onClick={() => {
                      this.setState({ showModal: true });
                    }}
                    className="card-img"
                    src={`${image}`}
                    alt="Card image cap"
                  />
                </div>
              ))
              : null}
          </div>
          <Modal
            bsSize="sm"
            show={this.state.showModal}
            onHide={() => this.setState({ showModal: false })}
          >
            <Modal.Header closeButton>
              <Modal.Title>Purchase Item</Modal.Title>
            </Modal.Header>
            <Modal.Body>Hello</Modal.Body>
          </Modal>
        </div>
      </section>
    );
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(<Gallery gallery={gry} />, document.getElementById('root'));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-bootstrap/0.31.5/react-bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/latest/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<div id="root"></div>
```

**Edit**
As a followup to your updated question, according to your screenshot, as far as react-bootstrap or react everything is looking fine. you would need to inspect your markup and styling to see what is hiding it.

Try to compare it with my example (inspect the `.modal-backdrop .fade .in`):
[image]

Comment: I already have the bootstrap css, and it works fine because I am using it else where and it works. Mmm, Could there be something blocking it? Like in a CSS file?

Comment: what do you mean by "_and it works fine because I am using it else where_"? elsewhere in the same project or in other projects? when you inspect the DOM with devtools, do you see the modal? maybe something is hiding it?

Comment: Good catch, im adding two photos to an edit to show what I found. (photos added)

Comment: yes i saw your screenshot. as far as react-bootstrap or react everything is looking fine. you would need to inspect your markup and styling to see what is hiding it. kinda hard for me to help with this as i don't have access to your code or rendered page :)

Comment: Okay, thank you @Sagiv b.g , I am going to accept your answer for the help. I will look and see if I can find anything, I'm using a template so this could be not fun .